# Parsing wikipedia xml with java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to use java to parse a wikipedia xml page, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=xml&rvlimit=10&titles=test

I am most interested in capturing the title represented here

```
<normalized>
  <n from="test" to="Test" />
</normalized>
```

I have the code to make the connection already, im just stuck on the getting and setting part of capturing the title Test.  All of the tutorials I find seem to be for a xml file on your computer but none have shown capturing one online and parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this one?

> parse(InputStream is)
>   Parse the content of the given InputStream as an XML document and return a new DOM Document

Use getInputStream() method of your URLConnection instance and use it to build XML file

Answer (score 0):

All of the tutorials I find seem to be for a xml file on your computer but none have shown capturing one online and parsing it.
//

parsing xml file online is no different from parsing one locally

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html)

Here is a quick example on how to use it

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new URL(URL).openStream()));

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("elementnamehere");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {

       Node nNode = nodeList.item(temp);
       Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
       if(eElement.getAttribute("elementnamehere") != null)
       {
           //Do something with it

       }
       else
       {

       }

    }
```